# Hide other bootstrap popover when one is open

Tags: javascript, jquery

From an [example](http://www.bootply.com/61233),i got this code to remove popover

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css'>


<div class="container">
  <h1>Bootstrap Popover Hide Open</h1>
<table>
  <tbody><tr data-toggle="popover" title="first row"><td>One</td><td><a href="#" class="btn">View</a></td></tr>
  <tr data-toggle="popover" title="second row"><td>Two</td><td><a href="#" class="btn">View</a></td></tr>
  <tr data-toggle="popover" title="third row"><td>Three</td><td><a href="#" class="btn">View</a></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>

<script>
$('[data-toggle=popover]').popover({
  trigger:"click"
});

$('[data-toggle=popover]').on('click', function (e) {
   $('[data-toggle=popover]').not(this).popover('hide');
});


</script>
```

But in my project i am using another version of jquery and bootstrap.

```
<link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
```

How to do same with new scripts not with older scripts.

Note : With new scripts `<td>` need to be clicked twice to open popup once it is clicked before.

[Code](https://jsfiddle.net/Bugfixer/vkpLdoyn/)

Comment: Try loading jquery script first, then bootstraps.

Comment: Remove `view-source:` from file in `src='view-source:https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js'`

Comment: No change at all.check code link below

Comment: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/17702